# How to access a hashmap in XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some java code which returns me a map, and I want to access this in XSLT.
I just saved the result in some variable called $map.

Tried accessing the value as key($map,'key1') with no luck.
where $map is what some java method returned and key1 is the key of one map entry.
I want to fetch its value.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Access from XSLT to external Java variables depends on which XSLT processor you are using; you need to tell us.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am using Xalan